# Stating two separate facts the same idea, but still keeping them exclusive of one another?

Tags: verbs, nouns, clauses, redundancy

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I wasn't even sure what question to look for.

In English, if I said the sentence:

> I helped clean and prune the garden in the backyard.

Of course, it seems that when I refer to cleaning and pruning, I am talking about the garden in the backyard. My question is, how can I make it seem like I am talking about *cleaning the backyard as a whole*, but only *pruning the garden*, without any redundancy?

If I say:

> I helped clean the backyard and prune the garden in the backyard.

Is it not redundant to say "backyard" twice?

Comment: Isn't it accepted that the garden is going to be in the backyard, rendering the second backyard redundant? E.g. "I helped prune the garden and clean the backyard"

Comment: I helped clean the backyard and prune its garden.

Comment: Probably a better question for [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't know if it's BrEng in general, or my experience in particular, but a garden _in_ a backyard doesn't quite ring true to me. Broadly, you either have a (back)garden _or_ a backyard. A garden might contain a mixture of flowerbeds, lawns, and concreted/decked areas, whereas in my mind a backyard is going to be mostly concrete (or perhaps bare earth) _possibly_ with "a bit of a border".

Comment: There's a garden in the backyard; I helped clean the backyard and prune the garden.

Comment: I helped clean the backyard and prune the back garden. Back garden, side garden, and front garden are perfectly normal terms.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to just ignore the location of the garden, and say:

> I helped clean the backyard and prune the garden.

because it's not likely that the specific location of the garden is important. But if there are multiple gardens, and you want to make it clear that you only pruned the one in the backyard, then repeating the phrase isn't really redundant, it's necessary to express the full meaning. You could replace *in the backyard* with *there*, to refer back to a previously mentioned location:

> I helped clean the backyard and prune the garden there.